# ShellToastNotificationReceived unable to change UI

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, push-notification, mpns

I have registered for Push Notification services on my WP 8 App.

when my app running on Background As Toast notification got it Update not only MVVM but also 
the View (UI) on the other hand of this

when my app running in foreground As Toast Notification occut it Update Only MVVM and Unable to update UI at that instant, it may update when i manually refresh the page

```
 pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
```

As the Toast Occur the above event is fired

code:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  this method runs when user Click to the incoming toast 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {

        ApplicationSetting _App = new ApplicationSetting();
        _App.Load_TaskRefresh();
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your Model/ViewModel?

Comment: yup........................

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the the event `ShellToastNotificationReceived` is not fired on the UI thread. So everything inside (that requires UI changes) should be wrapped inside a dispatcher. May be you can try something like this:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    ApplicationSetting _App = new ApplicationSetting();
    _App.Load_TaskRefresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) here says *"On devices without Windows Phone 8 Update 3, toast notifications are not displayed when the target app is running in the foreground."* , Anyway toast notification is something that grabs your attention back to the app, when already in foreground wont a custom message within an app help ?